# Longest alphabetical substring

Tags: python, while-loop

Write a program that prints the longest substring of a given input string s such that the characters of the substring are in alphabetical order. For example, if s = 'azcbobobegghakl' , then your program should print the substring 'beggh' (without the double quotes). In the case of ties, print the first substring. For example, if s = 'abcbcd' , then your program should print 'abc'. (Note that a substring of a string is a sequence of consecutive characters of the string.)
sample input: azcbobobegghakl
sample output: beggh
The longest substring that starts at index 0 (and whose characters are in alphabetical order) is 'az', at index 1 is 'z', at index 2 is 'c', at index 3 is 'bo', etc. The longest among all these substrings is the susbtring 'begg' that starts at index 7. Hence, the output is 'beggh'.

```
s=input()
ans=s[0]
#finalanswer=fans
fans=""
i=1
while i<len(s):
    if s[i]>=s[i-1]:
        ans=ans+s[i]
    elif s[i]<s[i-1]:
        ans=s[i]
    if len(ans)>len(fans):
        fans=ans
    if len(ans)==len(fans):
        if ans[0]<fans[0]:
            fans=ans
        elif ans[0]>fans[0]:
            fans=fans
    i+=1    
print(fans)
```

im a beginner my code passes 4/5 of the test cases and i cant find the error (i cant see the input of the test case in which i get a wrong output)

i tried a few inputs of my own to find the wrong output but i cant seem to get it
i did find the right code in a much simpler way online but i still want to know my mistake

Comment: You don't need the `if len(ans) == len(fans):` condition. You seem to be breaking ties by using the first letter of each substring. But you're supposed to break ties by using the first one in the input string. This already happens by only replacing `fans` if the new answer is longer.

Comment: And `fans = fans` doesn't do anything, what's the point of that?

Comment: @Barmar these are just for my own understanding, ive started python just a few days back, ill change those lines to #comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to check if the new answer is longer than the old final answer after adding a character.

You don't need the code that runs when `len(ans) == len(fans)`. It's replacing the final answer if the first character of the new answer is lower than the first character of the old answer, but that's not part of the requirements. Maybe you misunderstood what they meant by "first substring"; they didn't mean alphabetically first, they meant the one that appears first in the input. This is accomplished by only replacing the final answer when the new answer is longer, not equal.

```
def longest_increasing_substring(s):
    ans=s[0]
    fans=ans

    for i in range(1, len(s)):
        if s[i]>=s[i-1]:
            ans += s[i]
            if len(ans) > len(fans):
                fans = ans
        elif s[i]<s[i-1]:
            ans=s[i]

    print(fans)

longest_increasing_substring('azcbobobegghakl')
longest_increasing_substring('abcbcd')
```

Comment: the code gives an incorrect output in the same test case as mine, [link] (https://imgur.com/a/H2vFLQb)

Comment: It didn't work in the case where everything is in reverse order, because `fans` was initialized to an empty string. I've initialized it to `ans`, now it should work.

Comment: Wow, it's beautiful your solution.

Answer (score 2):

> *"... Write a program that prints the longest substring of a given input string s such that the characters of the substring are in alphabetical order. ..."*

You'll need to maintain the *maximum length*, and the *starting index* of the sub-string.

In this example, *m* is the maximum, and *a* is the *starting index*.
Assign the value at *j* to *c* when it's greater-than or equal to *c*, otherwise determine if it's a maximum and update *m* and *a*.

```py
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
n = len(s)
m = 0
a = 0
for i, c in enumerate(s):
    for j in range(i + 1, n):
        if s[j] >= c: c = s[j]
        else:
            if j - i > m:
                m = j - i
                c = s[j]
                a = i
            break
print(f"max= '{s[a:a + m]}' ({m}, from {a} to {a + m})")
```

Output

```
max= 'beggh' (5, from 7 to 12)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain exactly what you want to do? Your description is not enough clear.

With the information that you gave I tried to modify slightly your function like this:

```
s = input()
ans = s[0]
fans = ""
i = 1

while i < len(s):
    if s[i] >= s[i-1]:
        ans = ans + s[i]
    else:
        if len(ans) > len(fans):
            fans = ans
        elif len(ans) == len(fans) and ans < fans:
            fans = ans
        ans = s[i]
    i += 1

# After the loop, you need to compare ans and fans one more time 
# because the last valid substring might not have been compared.
if len(ans) > len(fans):
    fans = ans
elif len(ans) == len(fans) and ans < fans:
    fans = ans

print(fans)
```

The changes I've made:

1. Moved the comparison of ans and fans inside the loop so that it's checked every time ans is reset.
2. Added a final comparison after the loop to handle cases where the longest substring might be at the very end of the string s.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: In the OP's code, he compares the length of `ans` and `fans` in every iteration, so no special case is needed after the last iteration.

Comment: 2. i tried the input, pqrabcd in my code and it gave the correct output where the longest substring is at the very end of the string s.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you want to do? Your description is not enough clear. @Deotyma, my code gives an incorrect output for a particular input, its a question on hackerrank and i cant see for which input my code gives an incorrect output.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution :

```
def fn(s):
    curr, fans = s[0], s[0]

    for a in s[1:]:
        if a >= curr[-1]:
            curr += a
        else:
            curr = a
        fans = max(fans, curr, key=len)
        
    return fans
```

Output :

```
print(fn("azcbobobegghakl")) # 'beggh'
print(fn("abcbcd")) # 'abc'
```

Intermdiates :

```
0 :  fans=a      curr=az
1 :  fans=az     curr=c
2 :  fans=az     curr=b
3 :  fans=az     curr=bo
4 :  fans=az     curr=b
5 :  fans=az     curr=bo
6 :  fans=az     curr=b
7 :  fans=az     curr=be
8 :  fans=az     curr=beg
9 :  fans=beg    curr=begg
10:  fans=begg   curr=beggh
11:  fans=beggh  curr=a
12:  fans=beggh  curr=ak
13:  fans=beggh  curr=akl
----------------------------
0 :  fans=a      curr=ab
1 :  fans=ab     curr=abc
2 :  fans=abc    curr=b
3 :  fans=abc    curr=bc
4 :  fans=abc    curr=bcd
```

Comment: i have currently not started using max function and as i said i did find much easier solutions online but i would like to find the error in my code